# can git have remote work-tree (used to checkout to remote server)?

Tags: git

Is it possible to set something like this with GIT:
`GIT_WORK_TREE=ssh://user@env.example.com/path/to/folder`
?
I need this to checkout a branch to another server which doesn't have git set up

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar with sshfs for example.

http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

(on linux...)

Comment: Thanks, how can I integrate this with GIT?

Comment: You can mount the remote filesystem as a local directory with this tool, and you can use git in this directory if it were a local directory. Theoreticaly...

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. I also was thinking about setting up some script that would check if the folder is updated and send files to remote. What do you think about such approach?